# How to write not equal sign in sphinx rst document

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I display this symbol after compiling my rst file?

[image]

Comment: :math:`\neq` is not working? (\neq should be surrounded with ` but SO uses it to show the code)

Comment: @storaged, no it did not work. I haven't used :math: before and not sure if i need any special config to make it work.

Comment: @storaged, i am getting zero character shows up if i use    :math:`\neq` and i get :math: \neq if I use :math: `\neq` (note i add one space between : and `)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about the ≠ (not equals) character.  Just type it into your reST, or copy paste the actual character where needed:

```
true ≠ false
```

Comment: latex will need extra config in conf.py of `latex_elements['preamble']` to `r'\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2260}{\ensuremath{\neq}}'`

Comment: True. The OP is not clear which output format they want. @jfbu does your comment also require a font that supports that character and a minimum version of Sphinx?

Comment: My comment requires no special font because it uses math mode to render the glyph. On older versions of Sphinx, the config variable was called `latex_preamble` but it was `"Deprecated since version 0.5"`, and got removed at `1.6`. If document uses `latex_engine='xelatex'` then my comment **doesn't apply**, rather one needs an OpenType font with the glyph. The default one for LaTeX (Latin Modern) doesn't but a better choice of default OpenType font for `xelatex` will apply in future (perhaps CMU, or Libertinus, but the latter requires recent TeXLive). Sphinx must choose a font coming with TeX.

Comment: (I am assuming even old versions of Sphinx LaTeX did `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`)

Comment: What output are you using, LaTeX, HTML, etc.? If HTML which Sphinx theme are you using? Does the character appear in the rendered source HTML when you View Source? Did you first do `make clean` to clear Sphinx's cache and rebuild all the docs from source? You must say more than "does not work", and include "I did X, Y, then Z, and observed the following" to get further support.

Comment: My apologies. I use html and the SO removes some characters that did not get escaped. To be precise, this does not work \*≠\*

Comment: What is "SO"? Significant Other? Come on, help me to help you, and answer the other two questions in my comment above.

Comment: SO = stackoverflow.com

Comment: BTW: if I directly type ≠, it will work fine. Problem happens when I try to use \*≠\*. I am checking the answer of your other questions...give me a few mins

Comment: This is the theme: https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme and Yes, I did make clean and \*≠\* will show as /

Comment: `*≠*` renders as `<em>≠</em>` when I do `make html`. Is that your goal? Else you should create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because you have not provided sufficient information to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thank you. I can live with just ≠ for now :)